# Can a Django Kwarg take a Tuple or List as opposed to a String or Integer

Tags: python, django

From my limited experience in Django so far i've only wanted to use Strings or Integers for a kwarg, is it possible to supply multiple values to 1 kwarg through a list or tuple?

Example edit**

I'm building a DetailView that has the ability to be filtered like so:

```
    <ul class="list--inline--buttons left">
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-dropdown="role-line">Role Line <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <ul id="role-line" class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content>
                {% with 'all att mid def gk' as role_lines  %}
                    {% for rl in role_lines.split %}
                        {% cycle 'All' 'ATT' 'MID' 'DEF' 'GK' as role_lines_name silent %}
                        <li>
                            <a href="{% url url_string object.slug card_type|default:'all' rl sort_by|default:'ovr' %}">
                                {{ role_lines_name }}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endwith %}
            </ul>
        </li>
        {% if role_line %}
            <li class="active"><a href="#">{{ role_line|capfirst }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
```

Which builds `/all/att/ovr/`

So they can either filter for 1 role_line at a time not multiple role_lines. So i'd ideally like for the to be able to choose `att` then if they chose `mid` it would just append it to the role_line kwarg to create `/all/att/mid/ovr/`

Comment: You might be looking for a [multiple choice field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield)

Comment: I added an example, hope that helps.

Comment: @wim I'm not using a form or would it still work the same way if i changed the Model to that regardless?

Answer (score 0):

Well I do not know why you are doing it this way but the template is not the place for things like this. you can just add this to the context from you view as a list

```
role_lines = ['all','att','mid','def','gk']
context.update({'role_lines':role_lines})
```

Now you can do as you like with it in the template,you do not need the

```
with
```

you do not need the split too. if you need it in any format(title,lower,etc) do it in your view and pass it to the context from the view. if you need it in every template put it in a function and add it to the settings

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS
```

tuple and thats it.

Comment: Yea i know it needs refactoring, this is pretty old code and i'm learning more each day :) But thanks for the input i've already done the first bit earlier today.

Comment: @Dan you can accept this if it answers the question tx

Comment: It doesn't necessarily accept the answer of being able to use multiple values on 1 kwarg though which is what i was really after sorry!

Comment: it dose,you have the keyword role_lines in your context dict and all you do now is for value in role_lines and use each of the multiple values in role_lines as you like in your template its simple and cleaner.

Comment: I'm looking for multiple values in the URL not to be able to use in my template. So when i do self.kwargs['role_line'] it would return ['att', 'mid'] instead of just an string.